# Missing manifest file in ApplicationFiles folder with msbuild in NANT task

Tags: .net, msbuild, clickonce, manifest, nant

I have an application that is deployed via ClickOnce deployment.

I have used `NANT` in order to automate the publish process.

This is the Build part:

```
<target name="Build Client" depends="Clean" description="Build">
  <echo message="Building..." />    
  <exec program="${msbuildExe}" workingdir="." verbose="true">
    <arg value="${projectFile}" />
    <arg value="/target:Clean;Publish" />
    <arg value="/p:PublishDir=${testPublishFolder}" />
    <arg value="/p:ApplicationVersion=${version}" />
    <arg value="/p:Publisher=&quot;${publisherName}&quot;" />
    <arg value="/p:Product=&quot;${productName}&quot;" />
    </exec>
  <echo message="Built" />
</target>
```

Why is this creating `Client.application` (manifest file) only on root of the deployment folder, while publishing from VisuaStudio (clickOnce) creates identical file in the ApplicationFiles subfolder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered ...

```
   <!--COPY APPLICATION MANIFEST TO APPLICATIONFILES FOLDER-->
      <target name="CopyTestApplicationManifestToApplicationFilesFolder"     depends="Dependency target name" description="Update">
      <echo message="Copying..." />
      <copy 
        file="source file"
        tofile="target file" />
       <echo message="Copied" />
     </target>
```

I just copied it.